# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() - Redhat OS

Tags: php, libssh2

I installed required libraries for enabling ssh2 extension. I just followed this guide to install the php ssh2 extension. And it got enabled in my phpinfo page. But, still I'm not able to use ssh2_connection function within my php file. It says the following error message.

Please help to resolve this issue. **Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()**

Note: I'm using Redhat 6.3 Linux and I don't want any alternate library for this.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Linux/Q_27883937.html

[image]

Comment: Are you using PHP FPM and/or Apache? If so, you might need to restart it in order for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I'm using apache and already restarted the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed: There are two php.ini files in the server, those are below. The second one will be placed depends on your server OS. Just look out what are the location for php.ini (`locate php.ini`) and add the extension in the local.

```
/etc/php.ini
/usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pecl install -f ssh2
Then make sure "extension=ssh2.so" is in your php.ini/